# Sharepoint-Active Directory Profiles- Preferred Name are Not Getting updated

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to update the profiles of users in my SSP Application and I have 10000 records. Most of them are being updated for the first time and there are 21 records which are getting updated everytime I run the code.

I don't know why this is happening..

Could any body help me what's happening with my code.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPSite sc = new SPSite("http://xxxxx:81");
            ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(sc);
            HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpContext.Current = null;
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
            foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
            {
                if (profile[PropertyConstants.PreferredName].ToString().Contains("Domain\\"))
                {
                    profile[PropertyConstants.PreferredName].ToString().Replace("Domain\\", "").ToString();
                    profile.Commit();
                    NoOfUser++;
                }
```

}

Thank You

Hari Gillala

NHS Direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that there is a user profile import option in the SSP already are you? If you import AD properties only, use that. Only create a timerjob when the profile data is coming from another source. If there are any non-standard properties in AD, you can map those too by creating new profile properties and defining which AD property they map to.